# Woocommerce custom Endpoint content url

Tags: php, woocommerce, endpoints

i added a custom endpoint to myaccount menu and it corrispond to the Yith Woccommerce Wishlist.
I added this code in order to create the edpoint and show the content:

```
function my_custom_endpoints() {
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'yith-my-wishlist', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_endpoints' );

function my_custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'yith-my-wishlist';

    return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'my_custom_query_vars', 0 );

function my_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_flush_rewrite_rules' );

function my_custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    $items = array(
    'customer-logout'   => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
    'edit-account'      => __( 'My Profile', 'woocommerce' ),
    'yith-my-wishlist'  => __('My Wishlist', 'woocommerce'),
    //'dashboard'         => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
    'orders'            => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' )
    //'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
    //'edit-address'    => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
    //'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),



    );

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_custom_my_account_menu_items' );

function my_custom_endpoint_content() {
    include 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist/wishlist-view.php';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_special-page_endpoint', 'my_custom_endpoint_content' );
```

But the content doesn't appear. I think I got wrong on the url in the my_custom_endpoint_content() function.

I have a child theme and this code is in the functions.php of the child theme. I copied the folder of the yith plugin in the childtheme folder with the file i want to show.

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score -1):

your

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_special-page_endpoint', 'my_custom_endpoint_content' );
```

should have been

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_yith-my-wishlist_endpoint', 'my_custom_endpoint_content' );
```

it is in this format `'woocommerce_account_' . $key . '_endpoint'` where the `$key` in your case is `yith-my-wishlist`.

Also, I think `include 'yith-woocommerce-wishlist/wishlist-view.php';` will not work on the functions.php. You need the path to the plugin if this file is from a plugin.

Comment: You mean from wp-content/plugins ? And if I will customize this file, don't i have to get the child theme path ?

Comment: where is `wishlist-view.php` located?

Comment: Ah, it was a wrong type. I also changes the path to the absolute path, but i don't like this path. I put /home/[site_name]/public_html/wp-content.... Is it secure ?

Comment: wishlist-view.php is in wp-content/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist an i ahev copied it also in child_theme/yith-woccommerce-wishlist

Comment: look into the init file of the yith plugin.. there might be something like `define( 'YITH_<plugin>_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) )`, you can use that variable.